# Os "Class Components" morreram no React?

Tags: react, característica-linguagem, react-hooks

Antes da atualização 16.8 do React não era possível que componentes funcionais tivessem estado interno, então os **Hooks** chegaram para resolver este problema, dessa maneira, os componentes funcionais se tornaram o padrão do React.

Então os `Class Compenents` estão completamente "mortos" (ou quase isso)? Ou isso ainda seria uma suposição exagerada?

Comment: é opinião: eu acredito que não, porque inclusive as duas formas funcionam (`class` e `hooks`) e até o momento não vi algo ao contrário disso. Tem muito legado também eu acho que não

Comment: Na questão dos legados é verdade, porém uma pessoa que irá começar a aprender o React hoje, necessita aprender a utilizar os ```class components```?

Comment: Por mais que não tenha conhecimento em React, acredito que essa questão é a respeito de opiniões desde que ambos funcionem e não existe documentação oficial sobre este respeito.

Comment: Gabriel esse pergunta é muito pertinente, esse é o dilema, mas, a `lib` não impede que você faça em um ou em outro. Eu sei os dois porque comece na `class` agora quem começa é complicado mesmo, não tem resposta pra isso.

Comment: @CypherPotato existe documentação sim.

Comment: Eu trabalho com React e até agora só usei _class components_, e já criei um bocado de componentes, mesmo nos mais simples, apesar de ser mais volumoso o código (bem pouco), na minha opinião, deixa mais organizado, também, por vir do Angular, estou mais acostumado e prefiro o uso de classes. Sobre se é necessário ou não aprender _class components_, depende do quão você quer se especializar em React, para alguém que quer só conhecer por cima não precisa, mas se você pretende usar a lib continuamente com certeza precisa. Se alguém disser pra ti atualizar um código com classes irá refatorar tudo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR: As classes não vão morrer.** (ao menos, não tão cedo).

Como já foi respondido aqui, a [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#no-breaking-changes) cita que não há planos para remover classes do React. Porém a documentação traz diversos outros pontos que podem ser ressaltados aqui.

### Sem *breaking changes*

A partir do momento em que os *Hooks* foram trazidos sem *breaking changes* e numa versão intermediária (`16.8` e não `17`, por exemplo), nota-se que não é uma mudança brusca. Conforme o anúncio:

> Hooks não substituem seu conhecimento dos conceitos do React. Em vez
> disso, os Hooks fornecem uma API mais direta aos conceitos do React
> que você já conhece: objetos, estado, contexto, referências e ciclo de
> vida. Como mostraremos mais adiante, Hooks também oferece uma nova
> maneira poderosa de combiná-los.

Quando algo tem seu lançamento com uma abordagem de **complementar** (ou até mesmo de **melhorar**) ao invés de uma abordagem de **substituir**, a sua pergunta deveria ser "Quais as vantagens em usar Hooks se ainda posso usar Classes?" ao invés de algo como "Os componentes classe morreram?". Mas vou continuar a resposta abordando a pergunta original.

### Motivações

Dentre as motivações para a criação dos *hooks*, muita coisa gira em torno da frase **Classes confundem tanto pessoas quanto máquinas**:

> Além de dificultar a reutilização e a organização do código,
> descobrimos que as classes podem ser uma **grande barreira** para o
> aprendizado do React. Você precisa entender como `this` funciona em
> JavaScript, o que é muito diferente de como funciona na maioria dos
> idiomas. Você deve se lembrar de vincular (`bind`) os manipuladores de
> eventos. Sem propostas de sintaxe instáveis, o código é muito verboso.
> As pessoas podem entender `props`, `state` e o fluxo de dados
> *top-down*, mas ainda têm problemas com as classes. A distinção entre componentes funcionais e classes no React e quando usar cada um leva a
> discordâncias, mesmo entre desenvolvedores experientes do React.

Note que o discurso é algo como "você não vai 'perder' aquilo que já sabe, mas sim aplicará o conhecimento de outra maneira" e "não temos planos de remover classes do React". Isso chega a ser parecido com o relacionamento entre Android, Java e Kotlin (veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446535/100416) para mais detalhes).

Fica claro que parece uma boa ideia começar a usar *hooks*, sem precisar se preocupar em seus componentes classes pararem de funcionar.

### Adoção gradual

Vale reforçar o **TLDR** da documentação:

> **TLDR: There are no plans to remove classes from React.**

Não há planos para remover as classes do React. Elas não estão mortas, mas tudo indica que trabalhar com *hooks* se tornará o padrão em versões novas do React, simplesmente porque quando você usa uma tecnologia, a tendência é acompanhá-la e usar os novos recursos que ela dispõe.

> Fundamentalmente, os *Hooks* trabalham lado a lado com o código
> existente, para que você possa adotá-los gradualmente. **Não há pressa**
> **para migrar para *Hooks***. Recomendamos evitar qualquer "grande
> reescrita", especialmente para componentes de classe complexos
> existentes.

### Como a comunidade reagiu?

Quando esta resposta foi feita (abril/2020) já era possível dizer que a comunidade estava adotando os *hooks* e prever que isso seria o novo "padrão" - ao invés de pensar em criar um componente classe, você cria um componente funcional e vai adicionando os *hooks* conforme precisa.

Agora (dezembro/2020), uma boa parte das bibliotecas mais utilizadas e atualizadas estão fazendo uso de componentes funcionais e *hooks*, e eles realmente são bastante úteis - principalmente *hooks customizáveis*. Por exemplo, o `react-navigation` possui [componentes funcionais](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/bottom-tabs/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.tsx#L23) e [*hooks* próprios](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/useNavigationBuilder.tsx#L186), assim como o próprio `react-native` com [useWindowDimensions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/useWindowDimensions.js#L17). Existem vários outros exemplos, virou uma prática comum.

Apesar disso, ainda existem componentes classe por aí, como o [ContextMenu](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/src/renderers/ContextMenu.js#L72) da lib `react-native-popup-menu`, mas note que essa lib não recebe atualizações com tanta frequência. Se recebesse, provavelmente refatorariam para um componente funcional.

---

O conteúdo acima deve responder bem a pergunta, mas diante do tema *Hooks*, vale deixar como referência também o [FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) e o [vídeo de apresentação](https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM) da React Conf 2018.

Comment: Com um resposta destas, ter somente um up é uma injustiça tremenda! Parabéns

Comment: Não seja por isso... mais um up.

Answer (score 0):

Na própria documentação eles dizem que não pretendem remover as classes do React.

> Não temos planos de remover classes do React. Você pode aprender mais sobre a estratégia de adoção gradual para Hooks na seção inferior desta página.

A documentação com esse trecho você pode [ler aqui](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#no-breaking-changes)