# Qual empecilho técnico para o Android não suportar as novas versões do Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Gostaria de saber o porque a versão do **java** no **Android** permanece a mesma, depois de tantos anos. Em contra partida o **Kotlin** tem atualização com uma certa frequência, é uma questão técnica a estagnação do **Java**?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190247/2541

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, pesquisando, não encontrei nada falando **diretamente** sobre **empecilhos técnicos**, mas no tópico desta resposta sobre **Java 8** você verá algo sobre esse ponto.

## Kotlin e Java

Complementarei aqui alguns pontos mencionados pelo @Maniero, então leia a resposta dele também :).

#### 1. Kotlin é Open source, Java é da Oracle

O Java é uma linguagem proprietária enquanto o Kotlin é uma linguagem *Open Source*, o que vai de encontro com a mentalidade do [Android](https://source.android.com/), que também é um projeto Open Source. No site de [Desenvolvedores Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin), você pode encontrar a confirmação do que foi dito acima:

> O Kotlin é um projeto de código aberto e gratuito da licença do Apache
> 2.0. O desenvolvimento e distribuição como software gratuito são garantidos pela Fundação Kotlin. A escolha do Kotlin reafirma nosso
> compromisso com um ecossistema de desenvolvimento aberto à medida que
> expandimos a plataforma Android. Além disso, estamos ansiosos para ver
> a linguagem evoluir.

#### 2. Kotlin e Java no mesmo projeto

Um fato legal sobre *Kotlin e Java* é que você pode começar a migração de um projeto Java para Kotlin sem precisar migrar tudo de uma vez, já que o código em Kotlin acaba sendo compilado para código em Java.

> **Interoperável**
>
> Chame código baseado em Java com o Kotlin ou chame o Kotlin com código
> baseado em Java. O Kotlin é completamente interoperável com a
> linguagem de programação Java. Portanto, é possível ter o quanto de
> Kotlin que você quiser no seu projeto.

#### 3. Google e a abordagem Kotlin first

A Google [anunciou](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/google-io-2019-empowering-developers-to-build-experiences-on-Android-Play.html) que passou a desenvolver em Android com uma abordagem *Kotlin first* no [Google I/O 2019](https://youtu.be/ldM6QZy9e0s). Houve um slide com o título **Kotlin first: Why?** (minuto [25:48](https://youtu.be/ldM6QZy9e0s?t=1548) do vídeo) explicando benefícios (aos olhos da Google) do Kotlin em relação ao Java.

> **Kotlin first: Why?**
>
> - Strong adoption and community excitement
> - Developers are much happier using Kotlin
> - It is battle-tested
> - Customers feedback: focus investments on Kotlin

Então, falei muito de Kotlin aqui, mas é porque isso tudo é o motivo da Google investir mais em Kotlin do que em Java.

## Java 8

Você provavelmente ainda está pensando "E porque a versão Java permanece a mesma?". Se você ler sobre [Usar recursos da linguagem Java 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) encontrará o seguinte:

> O Android Studio 3.0 e versões mais recentes é compatível com todos os
> recursos da linguagem Java 7 e com um subconjunto de recursos da
> linguagem Java 8, que variam de acordo com a versão da plataforma.
>
> (...)
>
> O Android Studio não é compatível com todos os recursos da
> linguagem Java 8, mas essa compatibilidade está sendo ampliada em
> versões futuras do ambiente de desenvolvimento integrado. Dependendo
> da minSdkVersion usada, alguns recursos e APIs já estão disponíveis
> (...).

Provavelmente, isso é o mais perto de **empecilho técnico** que temos. O fato de o Android Studio precisar suportar as funcionalidades das novas versões Java e adaptar isso para todos os SDK Android.

## Entao devo parar de usar Java?

"Se a Google está fazendo as coisas primeiro em Kotlin, eu também deveria, certo? Java vai morrer no Android!"

Quase. Faz sentido começar a fazer as coisas em Kotlin porque ele está tendo um apoio maior da Google atualmente. **Não** faz sentido falar que você **deve** parar de fazer as coisas com Java e migrar todos seus aplicativos atuais com medo de pararem de funcionar. No Google I/O 2019 houve a seguinte frase (minuto [26:23](https://youtu.be/ldM6QZy9e0s?t=1583) do vídeo):

> Of course, we're going to keep supporting the Java programming
> language in many aspects.  Platform, Android Studio Support, Lint,
> like Docs, AndroidX, that's not going away.

Então, vale a pena migrar para Kotlin e começar a fazer as coisas em Kotlin, mas não existe um discurso de abandono ao Java. Veja o vídeo inteiro, apenas ressaltei pequenos pontos nessa resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Nenhum, ou quase. O maior motivo provavelmente é custo. è caro implementar todas essas novidades. E fica claro que a Google não está investindo mais no Java. Pra ela você deve usar Kotlin. Um dos motivos é que ela está sendo processada pela Oracle, e tem grande chance de perder em definitivo, já perdeu antes. Terá que pagar um valor bilionário por ter criado uma implementação própria do Java e a melhor saída para eles pode ser se livrar da linguagem. Pra que continuar investindo em algo que ela terá problemas em continuar usando?

Ela ainda o faz, algumas novidades do Java que eram simples de implementar forma implementadas. Algumas dessas novidades precisam ser ligadas para usar. Não sei se eles suportarão para sempre por isso não deixam ligadas por padrão. Ela suporta bastante coisa nova, mas demora um pouco para implementar.

Na verdade existe um ou outro ponto na biblioteca que pode ter algumas incompatibilidades, a Google se antecipou e depois veio algo oficial que era diferente, mas não sei se algo relevante.

O caminho mais seguro é adotar Kotlin. Se a Google agora faz *dog food* com Kotlin você deve fazer também. Ela não falará claramente se ela estiver preparando para abandonar pelo menos parcialmente uma solução, mas suas ações indicam claramente isto.

Comment: Se eu não engano, e me corrijam se estiver, o Kotlin roda em cima da JVM do Java, a JVM  é open source? E pode ser usado por outras linguagem como Kotlin, sem problema?

Comment: Sim em algumas plataformas, mas não no Android, ele usa o Android Runtime (ART). Ambos são abertos.

Answer (score 0):

O Android vem acompanhando sim as atualizações do Java. Em um projeto você pode utilizar tanto a versão mais recente do Java como a do Kotlin.

O fato de o Kotlin ter digamos "um acompanhamento com mais carinho", é porque ele tornou-se a linguagem oficial para desenvolvimento de aplicativos Android. De qualquer forma você pode sim utilizar o Java em sua versão mais recente.