# O que é e por que devo fornecer um “array de dependências” para os hooks do React?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

> Quem nunca se esqueceu de passar uma “dependência” ao array de dependência dos *hooks* do React?

É um infeliz fardo que toda pessoa que utiliza o React tem que estar atento: passar a dependência correta para o efeito ou *hook* que o exige. Criaram até um [*plugin* ao ESLint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) para facilitar isso. Passa uma aura de [*leaky abstraction*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/69296), mas não vem ao caso.

- O que é esse “array de dependências”?
- Por que ele é necessário nesse tipo de *hook*? Por que o React o exige?
- Como o React utiliza os valores que passo no array em questão?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa um hook do React em seu código, é possível fornecer um array de dependências como argumento opcional. Esse array é uma lista de valores de que o hook depende. Quando um desses valores mudar, o hook é chamado novamente.

Ele compara os valores atuais das dependências com os valores que estavam no array na última vez que o hook foi executado. Se todos os valores forem os mesmos, o hook não é chamado novamente. Se algum valor tiver mudado, o hook é chamado novamente e os valores atuais são passados como argumentos.

Isso é útil porque permite que o hook atualize seu estado e re-execute sua lógica de maneira apropriada quando os valores de dependência mudam. Isso é especialmente útil para os hooks que usam efeitos, como useEffect, pois permite que você controle quando os efeitos são executados.

Fornecer um array de dependências é opcional, mas é uma boa prática fazê-lo, pois pode ajudar a evitar problemas de performance e comportamentos inesperados em seu aplicativo. Por exemplo, se você não fornecer um array de dependências para um hook que usa useEffect, ele será executado a cada renderização, o que pode ser ineficiente e pode levar a comportamentos inesperados se o efeito depender de valores que mudam frequentemente.

Answer (score -1):

Vou dar um exemplo básico:

```
const MeuComponente = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incrementCounter = useCallback(()=>{
     setCounter(counter + 1);
  },[])

  return (
     <h1>{counter}</h1>
     <button type="button" onClick={()=> incrementCounter()}>Incrementar</button>

  )

}

export default MeuComponente;
```

Na forma acima sem um array de dependencias, no momento em que o react cria a função  `incrementCounter` o valor do `counter` é `0`.

Então ao chama-lo no click do botão, é feito o set de um novo valor sendo passado `(counter + 1)`. Note que esse `counter` vale `0`, logo o novo valor para `counter` sera `1`.

Porém nos próximos cliques no botão ao chamar a função de incremento, o valor da variavel counter lá dentro continua sendo 0, pois essa função só foi criada uma vez com o uso de useCallback, e o valor contido nela ainda é que o counter era 0.

Ou seja, a partir disso não importa quantos cliques dê no botão o valor de counter sempre será exibido como 1, mas dentro da função ele ainda é 0.

Isso significa que o valor de counter não foi atualizado lá dentro da função.

Para fazer com que o valor lá dentro seja atualizado e reflita o valor real, é necessário inclui-lo no array de dependencias.

Isso faz com que a função sofra uma atualização e que os valores contidos lá dentro sejam atualizados com base nesse array de dependencias.

```
const MeuComponente = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incrementCounter = useCallback(()=>{
     setCounter(counter + 1);
  },[counter])

  return (
     <h1>{counter}</h1>
     <button type="button" onClick={()=> incrementCounter()}>Incrementar</button>

  )

}

export default MeuComponente;
```

Claro que é só um exemplo, o ideal seria ao fazer setCounter(prev=> prev + 1), isso evitaria ter que passar dependencias ao useCallback.