# Como usar componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount e declarar o estado inicial em componentes funcionais?

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou tentando fazer uma conversão de componente de classe para componente funcional.

O código que tenho é:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = SelectionToolbarStore.getState();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    SelectionToolbarStore.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    SelectionToolbarStore.removeChangeListener(this.handleChange);
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState(SelectionToolbarStore.getState());
  };
...
```

O que eu fiz até agora:

```
const SelectionToolbar = () => {
  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);

  //   this.state = SelectionToolbarStore.getState();
  // }

  componentDidMount() {
    SelectionToolbarStore.addChangeListener(this.handleChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    SelectionToolbarStore.removeChangeListener(this.handleChange);
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState(SelectionToolbarStore.getState());
  };
```

O que eu quero fazer agora é transformar esses `componentDidMount()` e `componentWillUnmount()` em Hooks, mas não estou sabendo como.

Também quero se converter `this.state = SelectionToolbarStore.getState()` para `const [state, setState] = useState(SelectionToolbarStore.getState());` está correto, não sei se faz sentido.

Comment: Não sei de onde vem `SelectionToolbarStore`, mas o que você sugeriu parece certo. Qual o problema no código do `useState`? Sua dúvida é, então, somente sobre `componentDidMount()` e `componentWillUnmount()`?

Comment: O ```SelectionToolbarStore```vem dos meus stores. A dúvida é sobre ```componentDidMount()```e ```componentWillUnmount()```sim. Porque embora o site não quebrou a funcionalidade que eu queria que ocorresse não acontece

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Hooks

Você substituirá as funções de ciclo de vida por hooks. O estado também. Por isso, leia [O que são React Hooks?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/514280/100416) caso tenha alguma dúvida sobre eles de maneira geral.

## `useEffect`

O hook [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) **pode** ter um comportamento similar ao `componentDidMount` e `componentWillUnmount`. **Pode** porque ele possui um array de dependências, que indica quando o callback passado deve ser executado novamente.

O hook é executado após cada render, mas o callback é executado apenas se algo dentro do array de dependências for modificado. Então, se o array for vazio `[]`, funcionará como o `componentDidMount`.

No `useEffect`, podemos também retornar um [callback para "limpar" o efeito](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1). O React executará o *clean up* quando o componente desmontar. Entretanto, como mencionei anteriormente, o `useEffect` é executado em todo render, não apenas uma vez. É por isso que o React também limpa o efeito de renders anteriores antes de executar o efeito novamente no próximo render.

Em resumo, o *clean up* é executado antes do efeito ser acionado novamente. Caso o array de dependências seja vazio, o comportamento será como o do `componentWillUnmount`.

```
function Component() {
  // O primeiro argumento é o callback a ser executado.
  // O segundo argumento é um array vazio, que fará com que o callback seja executado
  // apenas no primeiro render.
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleChange = () => {
      this.setState(SelectionToolbarStore.getState());
    };
    SelectionToolbarStore.addChangeListener(handleChange);

    return () => {
      // Aqui o clean up será executado apenas quando o componente for desmontar
      SelectionToolbarStore.removeChangeListener(handleChange);
    }
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

## `useCallback`

Note que eu declarei a função `handleChange` dentro do `useEffect`, já que ela é usada apenas ali. Caso contrário, precisaria declarar fora e utilizar como dependência do hook.

Nesse caso, poderia fazer uso do [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) para que o React não crie uma nova referência da função a cada renderização. Eu falo um pouco sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/514391/100416). O código ficaria assim:

```
function Component() {
  const handleChange = useCallback(() => {
    this.setState(SelectionToolbarStore.getState());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    SelectionToolbarStore.addChangeListener(handleChange);

    return () => {
      SelectionToolbarStore.removeChangeListener(handleChange);
    }
  }, [handleChange]);

  return null;
}
```

**Esse código funcionará do mesmo jeito que o outro, com o array de dependências vazio.** Isso porque a referência da função será criada uma única vez, graças ao `useCallback`, que será no primeiro render. É importante entender isso.

## `useState`

O valor inicial do `useState` deve ser declarado como informado na pergunta. O valor inicial é estabelecido no primeiro render. Pode ser uma importação, pode ser passado por prop, pode ser uma constante.

```
import { valor1 } from './valor1';

function Component({ valor2 }) {
  const [val1, setVal1] = useState(valor1);
  const [val2, setVal2] = useState(valor2);
  const [val3, setVal3] = useState('Qualquer coisa');

  return null;
}
```